# Do ARM templates provide a way to capture the logs during creation of resources

Tags: azure, logging, azure-rm-template

we have ARM template which creates the azure resources. While we run the powershell script which created the resources, we want to log all the info.

we want to know if any logging functionality which azure ARM template provides

the list of resources we are as follows :
- storage account
- automation account
- key-vault
- Sql server pool
- functionApp etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are some of the general configurations you can use for the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` to get the most amount of logging from the command. You may lookup the equivalent `AZ` cmdlet, if you need to.

You can use the `-Verbose` and `-DeploymentDebugLogLevel All` parameters to get some more logging info. Note that the Deployment debug parameter will cause a warning to show up in your console output stream.

You can use the `-ErrorVariable ErrorMessages` parameter to get the error messages and then use them appropriately in your script.

Lastly, you can use the `JSON output` of the cmdlet to get some insights, if any.

Below is how the cmldet typically looks like for me..

```
$jsonOutput = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name  $DeploymentName `
        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -TemplateFile $TemplateFileToDeploy `
        -TemplateParameterObject $TemplateParameters `
        -Force -Verbose `
        -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All
```

Answer (score 0):

closest you can get is launch `new-azresourcegroupdeployment` with the `-verbose` switch, that would give you some idea whats going on, but I dont really think you are interested in that, you are mostly interested in errors. Fairly certain `new-azresourcegroupdeployment` outputs those.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. We will try this out.